# Injectivity and surjectivity.

Tags: functions

Determine if the following are injective or surjective, if both then find the inverse:

i. $g: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$,  $g(x) = \left [\dfrac{3x+1}{2} \right]$

ii. $g: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$,  $g(x) = \left [\dfrac{3x+1}{3} \right]$

iii. $g: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$,  $g(x) = \left [\dfrac{3x+1}{4} \right]$

For i,ii I'm pretty sure they are both injective, but not surjective (is this correct?). For iii) I'm pretty sure that it is surjective, but how would I prove it? I have no idea whether or not it is injective so that's where I need help proceeding.

where $[y]$ represents the integral part of $y$.  That is:

$[y] = \max\{ r \in \mathbb{Z} | r \leq y \}$

Comment: Hmm... are you sure that's not the fractional one?

Comment: @MarcinŁoś: the codomain is ${\mathbb{N}}$...

Comment: Just deleted the first comment since it's incorrect.  Sorry about this.  An integral part, according to the site I found, is "The integral part of $x$ is the greatest integral number, that isn't exceed $x$"

Comment: Try computing the value of $g$ for a few consecutive values of $x$, e.g. $x = 0, 1, 2, 3, 4,...$.

Comment: Don't forget that $\mathbb{N}$ consists of all counting numbers, including $0$ (though some mathematicians neglect $0$ in the set of natural numbers.)

Comment: @Warz : unfortunately people don't seem to agree whether $0$ is a natural number.  You should explicitly say whether you do here.

Answer (score 0):

The answers are:  (i,ii) are injective; (ii,iii) are surjective; thus, (ii) is bijective.

The easiest to start with is (ii):  Since $$\left\lfloor \frac{3x+1}{3} \right\rfloor = \lfloor x + {\textstyle \frac{1}{3}} \rfloor = x + \lfloor {\textstyle \frac{1}{3}} \rfloor = x$$ for all $x \in \mathbb N$, it follows that (ii) is a bijection, being the identity function on $\mathbb N$.

For (i), you want to show that if $x \ne y$, then $g(x) \ne g(y)$.  You can do this by considering the cases when $|x-y| \ge 2$ versus $|x-y| = 1$ separately, the latter case using the fact that if $|x-y| = 1$, then exactly one of $x$ and $y$ is odd.  To prove that (i) is not surjective, it suffices to find a positive integer $z$ such that $g(x) \ne z$ for any $x \in \mathbb N$.

For (iii), show that there exist two distinct positive integers $x \ne y$ such that $g(x) = g(y)$, hence it is not injective.  To show surjectivity, try to find an explicit relationship between any given $z \in \mathbb N$ and $x$ such that $g(x) = z$.

Comment: Here's another hint for the surjectivity of (iii):  Consider four cases:  $x = 4k$, $x = 4k+1$, $x = 4k+2$, and $x = 4k+3$, where $k \in \mathbb N$.